# Android: Experiencing "silent" crash when opening Developer Options programmatically from application

Tags: android, kotlin, crash, settings

I'm experiencing a "silent" crash when Attempting to open the `Developer Options` programmatically with

```
    override fun openDevelopmentSettings() {
        val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS) //Silent-crashes the app on my phone, but not emulator. What?
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Opening the `About Phone` Settings however works perfectly fine when replacing the above param with `Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS`

Setting Android Studio's Logcat panel to `Error` and `No Filters` produces the following, where the `About Phone` Settings produce no errors:

```
2021-04-12 20:43:03.576 1586-2265/? E/UserRestrictionsUtils: Unknown restriction queried by uid 1000 (com.android.providers.settings et al): null
2021-04-12 20:43:03.577 1586-2265/? E/UserRestrictionsUtils: Unknown restriction queried by uid 1000 (com.android.providers.settings et al): null
2021-04-12 20:43:03.592 15832-15832/? E/ndroid.setting: Can't find memory status under: /sys/block/zram0/
2021-04-12 20:43:03.641 674-9189/? E/libnos_datagram: can't send spi message: Try again
2021-04-12 20:43:03.662 674-9189/? E/libnos_datagram: can't send spi message: Try again
2021-04-12 20:43:03.745 15832-15832/? E/BtHDAudioCtr: Active device is null. To disable HD audio button
2021-04-12 20:43:03.854 15832-15832/? E/BtHDAudioCtr: Active device is null. To disable HD audio button
2021-04-12 20:43:03.864 15832-16203/? E/ndroid.setting: Can't find memory status under: /sys/block/zram0/
```

Please note that the `Developer Options` menu does open, just my application's process crashes upon opening. Clicking the back button from the `Developer Options` relaunches my app instead of resuming as the process is dead.

I have used another app that also programmatically opens the `Developer Options` and do not experience the crash.

I have tried both debug and release builds.

I have also tried wrapping the code in a try-catch block, but when debugging the catch block isn't hit.

I unfortunately don't have another physical device to test on, **but an emulator of the same device and API level doesn't reproduce the crash**.  What's going on here? Is my `Pixel 3` at `Android 11` `(RQ2A.210305.006)` corrupted?  Memory error?  Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.